# JQuery - Change $_GET variable on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a series of buttons that update my website's $_GET['year'] variable. I want the buttons to work on these pages:

- example.com
- example.com/?search=foo
- example.com/?search=foo&year=2015.

So for example if I clicked on `<a>2016</a>` my 'year' tag would be updated to `year=2016` and the webpage would show search results or everything from that year. I've tried using a JQuery AJAX like so:

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dateDropdown">
                    <li><a>2016</a></li>
                    <li><a>2015</a></li>
                    <li><a>2014</a></li>
                </ul>


            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".dateDropdown>li>a").each(function() {
                        $(this).click(function() {
                            alert("pressed");
                            $.get({
                              url: "index.php",
                              data: $(this).html(),
                              callback: alert("sent")
                            });
                        ;})
                    ;})
                ;}
            </script>
```

Currently I'm getting the "pressed" and "sent" alert, but the webpage is not updating. I figured I could probably get it to work using window.location and regex to change or add 'year' to the URI, but this way would be much neater.
Any ideas?

Comment: `data: { year: $(this).html() }`

Comment: Are you expecting content on your page to change? Is there a specific reason why you want the URL to change?  It's not really clear what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you want to update on `click` then why aren't you using `click` event?

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ I'm hoping that the search area will show me only results from that chosen year

Comment: @Saurabh I'm using the .click() event within the .each() function

Comment: Well then you're missing an awful lot here.  You need the actual PHP code that's going to handle this request.  You also need a success/response handler on the ajax that will take the response and display it on the page.  But if you are really needing the URL to actually update, then why not simply use a link for this? Ajax is typically used when you _don't_ want to update the URL.

Comment: The only reason that I don't want to use a link is so that on the homepage I can click on "2015" form my navbar and go to `example.com/?year=2015`, and then on the search page I can change the year without removing the other filters (so that the url stays as `example.com/?search=foo&year=2015&tag=item&page=3` and is linkable). I was under the impression that GET was for server-accessible variables that the user can see in the URI and that POST was for hidden variables

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery.get params](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

In your situation, it would be something like:

```
$(".dateDropdown>li>a").each(function(index,elem){
    $(elem).click(function(){
        alert('Pressed');
        $.get('url', {search:'foo', year: $(this).text() }).done( function(){ alert('Done!')} )
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I still can't get the URI to update with this code. I replaced 'url' with '/index.php' (since that's where the code is being sent from and received). I'm getting the 'done!' alert though.
Also, what's the purpose of the (index,elem) parameters?

Comment: jQuery each iterates over all (previously) matched elements and represents them in callback with `index` - number of element in collection and `elem` - single element itself. Of course, these two vars you can name however you'd like.

Comment: If you get `alert('Done!')` it means call is successful . What isn't good?

Comment: The problem is that I have a php script that shows search results only when $_GET['search'] or $_GET['year'] exist, but they are not running when I press the year buttons. It only works if I type something like `example.com/?year=2015` into the address bar.

Comment: @OwenFfrancon You seem to be completely misunderstanding what ajax is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dateDropdown>li>a").each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                alert("pressed");
                $year=$(this).html();
                $.ajax({
                  method: 'post',
                  url: "query.php",
                  data: 'year='+$year,
                  callback: alert("sent")
                  success: function(e){
                    $('html').html(e);
                  }
                });
            ;})
        ;})
    ;}
</script>
```

copy the contents of `index.php` to `query.php`
and make the content of `index.php`

```
<html>
   <?php include 'query.php'; ?>
</html>
```